# React Native: How to reference current route in Navigator's navigationBar={}?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

Depending on which current route, I am trying to change up styles like the following, but getting an error: 'route is not defined'. How can I go about referencing the current route: route.name in the navigationBar={}?

```
<Navigator
 configureScene={...}
 initialRoute={...}
 renderScene={...}
navigationBar={<Navigator.NavigationBar style={route.name == 'Home' ? styles.homeNavBar : styles.normalNavBar} .../>}
/>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my current set up in `index.ios.js`:

```
class practice extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator){
    return (
        <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
    )
  }

  configureScene(route, routeStack) {...}

  render() {
    return (
        <Navigator
          configureScene={this.configureScene}
          initialRoute={{name: 'Login', component: Login}}
          renderScene={(route, navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
          style={styles.container}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              style={route.name == 'Home' ? styles.homeNavBar : styles.normalNavBar} //This is what I am trying to achieve
              routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
            />
          }
        />
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
class practice_style extends Component{

  renderScene(route, navigator){
    this._navigator = navigator

    return (
        <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
    )
  }

  configureScene(route, routeStack) {...}

  getNav = () => {
    return this._navigator
  }

  render() {
    const routes = this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
    route = routes[routes.length-1];

    return (
        <Navigator
          configureScene={this.configureScene}
          initialRoute={{name: 'Home', component: Home}}
          renderScene={(route, navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
          style={styles.container}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              style={route.name == 'Home' ? styles.homeNavBar : styles.normalNavBar}
              routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
            />
          }
        />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is an array, just pop the last one off the stack.

```
var currentRoute = navigator.getCurrentRoutes().pop();
```

[Navigator.getCurrentRoutes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/Navigator.js#L1222) clones the routes array so you can't destroy it by `pop`'ing something off it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set reference of Navigator like this

```
 render () {
   //To access route
   var routeName;
   if(this.navigator) {
      const routes = this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
      routeName = routes[routes.length-1].name;
   }

   return (
    <Navigator
     configureScene={...}
     initialRoute={...}
     renderScene={...}
     ref={(nav) => this.navigator = nav}
     navigationBar={<Navigator.NavigationBar 
       style={routeName == 'Home' ? styles.homeNavBar : styles.normalNavBar} .../>}
    />
 );
}
```

Above function returns array of routes, last element in that array will be your current route.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry but trying to figure out how to put it to work. How do I integrate it into what I am trying to achieve? Thank you!

Comment: Appreciate the quick response! I made an UPDATE in the original post. Please take a look. So I'm trying to get `route.name` whenever it re-renders and based on `route.name` display different styles for navigationBar={}, so either styles.homeNav or styles.normalNavBar. In relevance, where should I put the `const routes = this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
 route = routes[routes.length-1];` and how does the `ref` help achieve what I intend? Thank you Abhishek!

Comment: just checking to see if you've see my previous comment. Please let me know!

Comment: this `const routes = this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes()` is to access current route. so you can access `route.name` . you have to put this inside render function before `return();`

Comment: If it doesn't work can you recreate it on [rnplay](https://rnplay.org/)

Comment: Tried it but got `Cannot read property "getCurrentRoutes" of undefined` . I updated the original post with the code under UPDATED. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Ok put a null check before that. for the first time navigator reference will be undefined.

Comment: Think almost there... did `console.log(routeName)` after doing the check, but in the beginning  when the app runs, it logs undefined then after even if routing among pages it does not log anything. So there is no error but the styles don't switch. This is how 'Home' is pushed. `this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Home,
      name: 'Home',
      passProps:{rowData: rowData}
    })` Anything wrong with that? What could be the issue..

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure whats going wrong here. can you post the on github or rnplay, so I can have a look.

Comment: Here is a gist! https://gist.github.com/jaewonch/8d56d9f598fe68103b4454f31d6ba7f8 Hope that clarifies it. So in 'Home' component, that's when it should style to transNavBar. Thanks in advance Abhishek!

Comment: Just checking to see if you had a chance to look at the gist. Please let me know!

Comment: Hey  I'm sorry, Little busy thesedays

Answer (score 0):

I use `navigator.jumpTo()` to move through routes, so `navigator.getCurrentRoutes()` returned the last of my available routes, rather than the current route.

To get the current route, I used `navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute`